# MVC - Change background colour of divs using database rgb value

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, colors

I've got a table that displays the colour of my items using this expression.

```
 <td>@Html.DisplayFor(l => item.Colour)</td>
```

That shows the word for the colour that I've assigned (you can see that in the attached image).
[How the colour shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lQcB.png) I've also got a 'ColourRGB' value for all my items and I want to make this the background colour for each  tag. Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried css -- I am able to use css files in my MVC project, which is MVC 5, but I think I could use it in MVC 4 also -- see also answer below (is from an actual MVC 5 project)

Comment: I can use CSS to change all the tags to a single colour, but I need a different colour for each one. As far as I know, you can't do much proper coding in CSS, so I can't use anything like the expression I've used in my razor code.

Comment: One could try making th1, th2, etc, if there aren't too many of them (see answer below, and generalize), otherwise someone else will have to think of something ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<td style:”background-color:@item.Colour”>@Html.DisplayFor(l => item.Colour)</td>
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed it to <td style="background-color: rgb(@item.ColourRGB)">@Html.DisplayFor(l => item.Colour)</td> and that worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

In css, one can define a particular color such as

```
table th {
    padding: 6px 5px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #e8eef4;
    border: solid 1px #e8eef4;
}
```

The in the .cshtml file:

```
<th class="headerStyle">
```